# Object with a particle system doesn't show in render

Tags: rendering, particles

for some reason, my person will not show up when rendered. I have checked the material and it is fine. Not sure what i did. Hoping that someone can figure it out for me.

here's a link to the .blend file: [person](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6xONZ2msgKHUWpIbTF6MkgzQ2c/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: view port]
[image: rendered]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the body as an emitter for the eyebrow particle system, and you've accidentally unchecked *Emitter* in the Render panel of the Particle Settings. Re-check that box, and you should be good to go:

[image]